# I'm convinced that ref.auth is bugged

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I've tried a few weeks ago and it wasn't working, and I've tried again just now and it's still not working. I only assign on event handlers after auth completes. In my code, deferred mechanism is carried out using $scope.$watch.

Security rules:

```
{
"rules": {
"chats": {
  "$org": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth.org == $org"
  }
}
}
}
```

Service:

```
"$$fbase": ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    ...
    ref: function(path) { var self = this;
      var ref = new Firebase(self.url + path);
      self.ready = false;
      ref.auth(self.auth_token, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          if (console) console.log(path+" login succeeded.");
          $timeout(function() { self.ready = true; });
        }
      });
      return ref;
    },
    bind: function(ref, excludes, limit, start) { var self = this;
      var result = {total: 0, list: []};
      ref.on('value', function(data) { result.total = data.numChildren(); });
      return result;
    },
  }
}],
```

Controller:

```
QuickMsgCtrl: ['$scope', '$$fbase', '$timeout', 
    function($scope, $$fbase, $timeout) {
  var ref = $$fbase.ref("/chats/abc");
  $scope.$watch(function() { return $$fbase.ready }, function() {
    if ($$fbase.ready) {
      var data = $$fbase.bind(ref);
      $scope.listing = data.list;
    }
  });
}],
```

Chrome console:

```
/chats/abc login succeeded.
FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /chats/abc failed: permission_denied
```

At this point it's pretty clear to me that there's a bug on your side that's giving me permission_denied for a simple read, despite successful login.

And no, AngularFire is useless to me because it doesn't do auth and it's heavily bugged.

Comment: Are you able to successfully read/write from the security simulator in Forge with a sample token? Just want to eliminate security rules being the cause. (Unrelated to the question, I'd also be interested in finding out what bugs you're seeing with AngularFire!)

Comment: if you want to see the bugs in AngularFire, change priority of items. Then you'll see AngularFire unable to correctly move the items in the collection.

Comment: Thanks, I filed an issue to make sure we fix it! Re: the auth bug, have you tried doing a simple auth/read outside of Angular (i.e. from a small test page)?

Comment: Can you make a quick jsbin? If it doesn't work in the above Angular blurb, I have very little confidence that it should work with any fancier setups.

Comment: Simulator showed "Read was allowed." It's not a rule problem. ref.auth is broken.